# Installing SharePoint 2013 Foundation Preview

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, installation, prerequisites

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, I get the error below when installing the pre-requisites. It did the first round of updates then i rebooted and on the second lot of installs this came up. I've since tried rebooting and doing windows updates and still having the same problem

Error:

the tool was unable to install aplication server role, web server iis role 2013 preview

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Which OS are you installing on?

Comment: Windows 2008 R2 Datacenter

Comment: Could be missing SP1

Comment: Just checked and SP1 is installed (if you mean sp1 for the os)

Comment: Added an image of the services installed. It's a new server I've just had setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that I was running an older version of SQL Server than was supported, as pointed out in a comment above.

Requirements as follows:

> Minimum software requirements This section provides minimum software
>   requirements for each server in the farm.
>
> Minimum requirements for a database server in a farm:
>
> One of the following:
>
> The 64-bit edition of Microsoft SQL Server 2012.
>
> The 64-bit edition of SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1
>
> The 64-bit edition of Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (SP1)
>   Standard, Enterprise, or Datacenter or the 64-bit edition of Windows
>   Server 2012 Standard or Datacenter
>
> The SharePoint parsing process crashes in Windows Server 2008 R2 (KB
>   2554876)
>
> FIX: IIS 7.5 configurations are not updated when you use the
>   ServerManager class to commit configuration changes (KB 2708075)
>
> Hotfix: ASP.NET (SharePoint) race condition in .NET 4.5 RTM:
>
> Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 (KB 2759112)
>
> Windows Server 2012 (KB 2765317)
>
> Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.5
>
> Minimum requirements for a single server with built-in database:
>
> The 64-bit edition of Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (SP1)
>   Standard, Enterprise, or Datacenter or the 64-bit edition of Windows
>   Server 2012 Standard or Datacenter
>
> The SharePoint parsing process crashes in Windows Server 2008 R2 (KB
>   2554876)
>
> FIX: IIS 7.5 configurations are not updated when you use the
>   ServerManager class to commit configuration changes (KB 2708075)
>
> Hotfix: ASP.NET (SharePoint) race condition in .NET 4.5 RTM:
>
> Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 (KB 2759112)
>
> Windows Server 2012 (KB 2765317)
>
> The Setup program installs the following prerequisite for a single
>   server with built-in database:
>
> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 - Express Edition
>
> The Microsoft SharePoint Products Preparation Tool installs the
>   following prerequisites for a single server with built-in database:
>
> Web Server (IIS) role
>
> Application Server role
>
> Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.5
>
> SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 Native Client
>
> Microsoft WCF Data Services 5.0
>
> Microsoft Information Protection and Control Client (MSIPC)
>
> Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 SP1 (x64)
>
> Windows Management Framework 3.0 which includes Windows PowerShell 3.0
>
> Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) 1.0 and Microsoft Identity
>   Extensions (previously named WIF 1.1)
>
> Windows Server AppFabric
>
> Cumulative Update Package 1 for Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 for Windows
>   Server (KB 2671763)
>
> Minimum requirements for front-end web servers and application servers
>   in a farm:
>
> The 64-bit edition of Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (SP1)
>   Standard, Enterprise, or Datacenter or the 64-bit edition of Windows
>   Server 2012 Standard or Datacenter.
>
> The SharePoint parsing process crashes in Windows Server 2008 R2 (KB
>   2554876)
>
> FIX: IIS 7.5 configurations are not updated when you use the
>   ServerManager class to commit configuration changes (KB 2708075)
>
> Hotfix: ASP.NET (SharePoint) race condition in .NET 4.5 RTM:
>
> Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 (KB 2759112)
>
> Windows Server 2012 (KB 2765317)
>
> The Microsoft SharePoint Products Preparation Tool installs the
>   following prerequisites for front-end web servers and application
>   servers in a farm:
>
> Web Server (IIS) role
>
> Application Server role
>
> Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.5
>
> SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 Native Client
>
> Microsoft WCF Data Services 5.0
>
> Microsoft Information Protection and Control Client (MSIPC)
>
> Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 SP1 (x64)
>
> Windows Management Framework 3.0 which includes Windows PowerShell 3.0
>
> Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) 1.0 and Microsoft Identity
>   Extensions (previously named WIF 1.1)
>
> Windows Server AppFabric
>
> Cumulative Update Package 1 for Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 for Windows
>   Server (KB 2671763)**

Answer (score 0):

Verify if you have Iisext.vbs in the c:\windows\system32 folder.
If this file is not available, activate the Web service (IIS) management tools via the add roles and features wizard.

Comment: It is there. I only have SQL 2005 - is 2008 required?

Comment: You SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(office.15).aspx